# Diagramm doesn't show timeline

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

So I have the problem that the diagramm I create with Python and Pandas doesn't show my timeline[image]

As you can see it doesn't show the time where the data was written into the data base.
My database looks like this:

```
id    hum   temp    time      date 
 1    74     23   15:35:22  2020-06-17
 2    81     23   15:37:28  2020-06-17
```

And that's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, datetime
from pandas import DataFrame

datum = str(date.today())

con = sqlite3.connect("/home/pi/test2.db")
sql = "SELECT * from data4 WHERE date in (?)"

df3 = pd.read_sql_query(sql,con, params=[datum])

def daily_hum():

    df3.plot(x = 'time', y= 'hum', kind='line', color='blue')
    plt.ylabel('temperature in C°')
    plt.xlabel('time')
    plt.savefig('/home/pi/flask/static/daily_hum.svg')
daily_hum()
```

So how can I show the timeline?

Comment: Works fine for me on matplotlib 3.1.1

Comment: I'm using 3.0.2 could this be the issue?@Sheldore

Comment: I can't say. try adding `plt.tight_layout()` before saving

Comment: Which `type` are your `time` and `date` columns? `str`, `datetime`, `timestamp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try:

```
# group datapoint by hours of day
df3.groupby([df3.time.dt.hour]).hum.mean().plot()
```

or

```
# group datapoint by minutes of day
df3.groupby([df3.time.dt.minute]).hum.mean().plot()
```

In this examples the column df3.time needs to be datatype datetime.

---

### Converting datatype string to datetime64

In case your columns df3.time and df3.date are strings.

```
# date and time to one column called datetime. converting to dtype datetime
df3['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime((df3.date + ' ' + df3.time))

df3.groupby([df3.datetime.dt.hour]).hum.mean().plot()
```

---

### Plotting all datapoints

If you don't want to group the data (df3.hum) by datetimepoints (one point for each hour of day) you could do the following.

```
# date and time to one column called datetime. converting to dtype datetime 
df3['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime((df3.date + ' ' + df3.time))

df3.groupby([df3.datetime]).hum.mean().plot()
```

Then you could think about another plot like [scatterplot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html) from pandas library.

Comment: That helped but when I run it now, it shows the timeline but the values are only one straight line

Comment: Your problem could be solved by using the following plot code.

df3.groupby([df3.datetime]).hum.mean().plot()

Comment: @Simon. I have edited my answer according to your problem. See _Plotting all datapoints_.

Comment: Thank you very very much . This helped me a lot thank you! Are u from Germany? @theompm

Comment: Yes I am from Germany. I try to improve my English skills by reading and answering on stack overflow. @Simon

Comment: Okay nice, I am also from germany and many thanks again